# clojure: create a lazy-seq containing another lazy-seq

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I would like to create  a lazy-seq containing another lazy-seq using clojure.

The data structure that I aready have is a lazy-seq of map and it looks like this:

```
({:a 1 :b 1})
```

Now I would like to put that lazy-seq into another one so that the result would be a lazy-seq of a lazy-seq of map:

```
(({:a 1 :b 1}))
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be appreciated

Regards,

Comment: Can you add a few steps to your final expected output, i cant fully understand the sense of your requirements

Comment: Hi tangrammer. Thx for your replying. I actually want no output at this point.  The point is that there is another function with takes as argument a seq of seq of maps, that` s to say (({:a 1 :b 1})).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of creating a list containing a list of maps:

```
=> (list (list {:a 1 :b 1}))
(({:a 1, :b 1}))
```

It's not lazy, but you can make both lists lazy with `lazy-seq` macro:

```
=> (lazy-seq (list (lazy-seq (list {:a 1 :b 1}))))
```

or the same code with `->` macro:

```
=> (-> {:a 1 :b 1} list lazy-seq list lazy-seq)
```

Actually, if you'll replace lists here with vectors you'll get the same result:

```
=> (lazy-seq [(lazy-seq [{:a 1 :b 1}])])
(({:a 1, :b 1}))
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do and why do you want both lists to be lazy. So, provide better explanation if you want further help.

Comment: Thx Leonid. And you were right that there is no need to make both lists lazy. It was an error in my reasoning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

generally, there's nothing special about having a lazy-seq containing many lazy-seq's, so i dont understand exactly what it is you are really after.

you could always do

```
(map list '({:a 1 :b 1}))   ;; gives (({:a 1, :b 1}))
```

we can even verify that it maintains laziness:

```
(def a
  (concat
   (take 5 (repeat {:a 1 :b 2}))
   (lazy-seq
    (throw (Exception. "too eager")))))

(println (take 5 (map list a))) ;; works fine
(println (take 6 (map list a))) ;; throws an exception
```